# This textFieldShouldReturn stopped working

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

This method is not working anymore on me, I have no idea why.  It just resigns the keyboard when the user presses enter or "done" in my case.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == UsernameEntry)
    {
        [UsernameEntry resignFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == PasswordEntry)
    {
        [PasswordEntry resignFirstResponder];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

**EDIT:**  Alright, I have the .h @interface declared to a UITextFieldDelegate, and I have used @shaik riyaz's simplified method, but the method is still not working

Comment: [textField resignFirstResponder];

Comment: Does the answer helped you?? or you still having prob ?

Comment: still having the problem, I have posted an edit to the question

Comment: is this method is called when you click on enter or done? ... try to add a break point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this . . .

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must set up the delegate properly in the ViewController, you need to implement `<UITextFieldDelegate>` and ensure its wired in correctly for each `UITextField`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem an I didn't have this after the .h @interface make sure you have
 after the name of the class you have the textfield.

For example:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```